# Botbuilder how to use default locale strings in case namespace hasn't defined it

Tags: node.js, locale, botframework

I am using the botbuilder framework. I have defined several namespaces for the dialogs I have created, such as `help` or `default`. For all of these I have also created json files in my `locale/en/` directory, and all is well.
However, I have a few sentences that are very common, and I don't feel like copying those over to each of the individual namespaces. I have tried using `index.json` as a 'fallback' in case the namespace file doesn't define the string. But it doesn't work for me. Contrary to what the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-localization) seems to suggest.

```
/locale
  /en
    /help.json
    /default.json
    /index.json <-- Doesn't work
/dialogs
  /help.js
  /default.js
bot.js
```

Say I have the following library in `help.js`, that :

```
lib = new builder.Library('help')
lib.dialog('/', (session) => {
  session.send('custom_cancel')
}
module.exports = lib
```

The library is used in `bot.js`:

```
bot.library(require('./dialogs/help'))
```

And `index.json` has this content:

```
{
  "custom_cancel": "My custom cancel"
}
```

Whereas `help.json` is empty:

```
 {}
```

Because `help.json` does not have `custom_cancel`, the bot will actually send `custom_cancel` as the string.

Again. I can copy paste the strings to both locations and there is no more problem. But that seems like an ugly solution to me.

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: @EzequielJadib I edited the question. Let me know if this makes it clearer to you.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Ah let me clarify, can you post the code you're using to call your other two .json files, e.g. the `bot.use()` section?

Comment: @StevenG. Perhaps this is clearer? I don't use `use` directly in this scenario. I have libraries that contain dialogs instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the more [explicit](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/interfaces/_botbuilder_d_.ilocalizer.html#gettext) version, which seems to help in more cases, but I am not fully convinced yet.

```
session.localizer.gettext(session.preferredLocale(), 'custom_cancel')
```

You can use the third argument for the namespace. It seems that `''` will point to the `index.json` file.